# Count how many times numbers repeat in list number by numbers

Tags: python-3.8

Consider the first number, say m. See how many times this number is repeated consecutively. If it is repeated k times in a row, it gives rise to two entries in the output list: first
the number k, then the number m. (This is similar to how we say “four 2s” when we see
[2,2,2,2].) Then we move on to the next number after this run of m. Repeat the process
until every number in the list is considered

Example:The process is perhaps best understood by looking at a few examples:

• readAloud([]) should return []

• readAloud([1,1,1]) should return [3,1]
• readAloud([-1,2,7]) should return [1,-1,1,2,1,7]

• readAloud([3,3,8,-10,-10,-10]) should return [2,3,1,8,3,-10]

• readAloud([3,3,1,1,3,1,1]) should return [2,3,2,1,1,3,2,1]

I have the following code:

```
def readAloud(lst: List[int]) -> List[int]: 

    answer:List[int]=[]


    l=len(lst)
    d=1

    for i in range(l-1):

        if(lst[i]==lst[i]):
            d = d + 1
           

            answer.append(d)
            answer.append(lst[i])

        if (lst[i-1] != lst[i]):
             d=1
             answer.append(d)
             answer.append(lst[i])

    return answer
```

Comment: What is the problem or error?

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: The code I have written is wrong and I couldn't  figure it out how to do it. Luckily "djangoliv" me solved the problem. And yes it is a homework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution (but this is not the only one :) )

```
def readAloud(lst):   
    answer = []
    count = 1
    prev_elt = lst[0]
    for m in lst[1:] + [None]: # we add Node for the last values
        if prev_elt == m:
            count += 1
        else:
            answer.extend([count, prev_elt])
            prev_elt = m
            count = 1
    return answer

print(readAloud([3,3,1,1,3,1,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I was so stress about this question. Really thanks you again.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping adjacent elements is exactly what [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is for.

```py
from itertools import chain, groupby

def read_aloud(numbers):
    r = ((sum(1 for _ in v), k) for k, v in groupby(numbers))
    return list(chain.from_iterable(r))
```

Examples:

```py
>>> read_aloud([])
[]
>>> read_aloud([1, 1, 1])
[3, 1]
>>> read_aloud([3, 3, 8, -10, -10, -10])
[2, 3, 1, 8, 3, -10]
>>> read_aloud([3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1])
[2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I haven't been taught with that method yet.